# Ajax $.post on page load - React

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I want to post data via `$.post` in ReactJS and use it in an api made to retrieve data from a database with some criteria like publisher_id. 
What I am trying to do is take the publisher_id from a special class called User and then post it via my React app into the api files. I stumbled upon a problem which is I can only use $.post when sending data to the server via a form with, usually, a `onSave` function. I am fully aware of how that works but my question is:

Is there a way to send data with `$.post` or anything right when the rendering process starts?

I have tried using `componentWillMount` for that matter but I stumbled upon another issue. I have noticed that usually, for `$.post` to work, an event must be triggered.

What kind of event should I use to do what I want?

**Code**

For the `$.get` method I use the following which works just fine:

```
componentDidMount: function () 
{
    this.serverRequest = $.get("get_user_id.php", function (publisher_id) 
    {
        this.setState(
        {
            publisher_id: JSON.parse(publisher_id)
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

What I need to do for my api to work is right after this retrieving of data happens, to post `publisher_id` into `read.php`, file responsable for retrieving only specific data from the database.

EDIT:

What I have tried doing is the following:

```
componentDidMount: function () 
{ //previous code
this.serverRequest = $.post("read_all_products.php", {
        publisher_id: this.state.publisher_id,
    })
}
```

As mentioned before, the retrieve of data fully works since when later in the render function trying to display it with {this.state.publisher_id} it will correctly show up.
What doesn't work is the post of data. I may not be fully aware of how I am supposed to do it since , again, I am trying to send it on page load.

EDIT2: 
I have also tried passing publisher_id as a prop from the main component, so the $.get method now happens there. Then I did the following:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
    this.serverRequest = $.post("read_all_products.php", {
        publisher_id: this.props.publisher_id,
    });

},

componentDidMount: function () {
    this.serverRequest = $.get("read_all_products.php", function (products) {
        this.setState({
            products: JSON.parse(products)
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

That didn't work and I tried sending a *fake* form using an onSave function:

```
    onSave: function (e) {
    $.post("read_all_products.php", {
        publisher_id: this.props.publisher_id,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}// used after this in the render method on a form with a button, both 
//have onSubmit and onClick set to {this.onSave}
```

I still look forward to somebody's help. I am pretty much stuck and have been for the past few days. I need to get this to work or I either need to change the authentication or keep being stuck on this.

The question is: How do I use $.post , in React, to send a prop called publisher_id to my .php api file on page load or even, say if anything else isn't possible, by making a button that sends the data with an empty form that presses itself once before the componentDidMount, probably in componentWillMount?

Comment: For a normal AJAX post you don't have to trigger an event. The way you have done it in your code, you have to, as you assigned it to `this.serverRequest`. But why are you using `$.get` for a POST?

Comment: I am using $.get to retrieve the publisher_id from its class and then set it to a state in componentDidMount. I am trying to use $.post to send that publisher_id to another php file that then selects an array of products from the database using the condition "...WHERE p.publisher_id = " . this->publisher_id . " ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by doing the following:

A solution for the code above doesn't exist. What I did is simply not passing the publisher_id to React at all. I simply opened the php session in my api and used the value saved is the $_SESSION variable.

After doing this, everything works the way I want it to.